# DAX - Text as an output of SUMX

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am getting an error if adding text "" as output of the IF function

The DAX code works OK if I add a number as the output of the IF condition, but I need to show the text "Below target" and "Above target"

How to fix this measure and have a text "" as an output of a SUMX function?

`Target = SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table1','Table1'[Customer ID],  'Table1'[Sales],  "MaxResut",MAX('Table1'[Sales])), IF([MaxResult]>=1000,"Above target","Below target"))`

Answer (score 0):

Your DAX is trying to sum a column of text values that are either "Above target" or "Below target". This throws an error because it doesn't make sense to add text values like that.

It's not clear what you are actually trying to do but if you wanted to test the sum of the max results, then this might make sense:

```
Target =
IF (
    SUMX (
        SUMMARIZE (
            'Table1',
            'Table1'[Customer ID],
            'Table1'[Sales],
            "MaxResut", MAX ( 'Table1'[Sales] )
        ),
        [MaxResult]
    ) >= 1000,
    "Above target",
    "Below target"
)
```

This does the comparison after summing rather than summing text values.